# SFTP connection to Ubuntu 22.04 for an old Cisco application

Tags: networking, server, ssh, sftp

I'm trying to connect an old Cisco sftp client to my sftp server running on Ubuntu 22.04. (I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-sftp-without-shell-access-on-ubuntu-20-04) setup)

When the client tries to connect, I get the following error:

> Sep 13 16:20:54 backuptest sshd[2294]: Unable to negotiate with X.X.X.X port 45234: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]

I have already tried to add a conf file like this one:

```
HostkeyAlgorithms ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

but now I still get:

> Sep 13 16:24:34 backuptest sshd[2311]: Unable to negotiate with X.X.X.X port 45423: no matching cipher found. Their offer: aes256-cbc,3des-cbc [preauth]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you know that this old Cisco sftp client can work with Ubuntu 22.04. You never said how old, old is.

Comment: Hi @David. It's Cisco Call Manager 10.5. The problem is not Ubuntu 22.04 itself, but the ciphers used by sftp

Comment: If it was me I would be asking Cisco.

Comment: I see. But Cisco does not provide support on 3rd party sftp server. For those interested in fixing it, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed in my case:

```
Ciphers +aes128-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
# If you authenticate using a keypair:
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```